# Returning an object or false in dynamic languages

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Consider the following JavaScript function:

```
function Foo() {
  function getPreferences() {
    if ([there is an existing preferences object]) {
      return preferences;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The calling code is:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var prefs = foo.getPreferences();
if (prefs) {
  // do something with prefs
}
```

- Is the pattern of returning an object if it exists, or false otherwise, seen as a good or bad practice? Other alternatives I can see are to return an empty object {} or null.
- Does this pattern have a name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

False seems like a strange choice.  `null` seems more natural.  Best of all, return default preferences and eliminate `if (prefs)`.

Comment: My fault: I meant more generally where a caller expects an object in return, but it might not exist. In some cases (like preferences) defaults would work, but not in others.

Comment: @Sean: it's not always possible, but returning a default object is possible in many more situations than most people expect.

Comment: @Sean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Comment: @Kevin: you are right, I will look for a way to return a default object.

Comment: @back2dos: thanks for the link, and name.

Comment: The Null Object pattern sucks. There are some places where you can reasonably default, but in *most* cases, you can't. It's not a good thing to fall back on and it's not a general answer to the problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: What really "sucks" are comments like the one you made. Not only is it simply wrong for a whole class of languages, but also it's worthless without verifiable arguments.

Answer (score 6):

I'd much rather see code that returns an object for success and `null` for not success.  Then, it at least feels like the function is behaving consistently.  It's return either an object or the standard way of saying no object `null`.  The same code:

```
if (prefs) {
    // do something
}
```

works either way, but returning `null` seems more consistent to me (as the lack of an object) than returning `false`.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I didn't realise that you don't need to write if (prefs !== null) explicitly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should either return a default value, or throw an exception . I like throwing exceptions for mandatory things, and delivering default values for optional things. Using null makes debugging a bit more icky, and precludes a key that has null as its value.

```
 function Foo() {
       function getParameter(name) {
               if ( [name does not exist] ) {
                    throw "no such key";
               }
               return [parameter value]
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer differs from others because I've taken your *specific use case* into account. On any other day, I'd use the `null` value check.

In this specific case, I probably wouldn't use any of your methods. I'd most likely use an object for preferences with a number of default key/value pairs for any settings that I need. That way, there isn't any special casing needed in any of your code (checks for `if(prefs)` are not needed).

Consider the following code (how I think I'd go about implementing it anyway):

```
function MyClass(o) {
    this.prefs = {
        var1: 0,
        var2: 1,
        var3: 2
    };
    for(key in o) {
        this.prefs[key] = o[key];
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.doFunc = function() {
    console.log(this.prefs.var1);
    console.log(this.prefs.var2);
    console.log(this.prefs.var3);
}

var o = new MyClass();
o.doFunc();

var p = new MyClass({var2: "foo"});
p.doFunc();
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/utkdf/)

Answer (score 2):

One sees lots of that pattern in javascript because of javascript's 'creative' [handling of falsey values](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/967-javascript-jems-active-logic-truthy-and-falsy.html).

While it is possible to do nifty stuff in javascript, I'm not sure a language designed in the space of ten days is something you'd want to emulate.

Answer (score 2):

Like other people said, it's `null` which must be returned, instead of `false`. Even with strongly typed languages, you may expect `false` from a method, which will have a different meaning than `null`. It's even more important in languages with no type checking. For example, PHP has a similar problem, perfectly [illustrated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) when using `readdir` method (below, quote and source code from PHP manual):

> Please note the fashion in which `readdir()`'s return value is checked in the examples below. We are explicitly testing whether the return value is identical to (equal to and of the same type as--see Comparison Operators for more information) FALSE since otherwise, any directory entry whose name evaluates to FALSE will stop the loop (e.g. a directory named "0").

```
/* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry\n";
}

/* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
    echo "$entry\n";
}
```